# Add data to specific column using writerows, lambda

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I've iterated through JSON objects returned to me via an API query, and can get the data (obj_key1) into my `target_csv`, but the data is showing up in the first column, not the `data` column, which I am trying to specify.

Example JSON:

```
[{'obj_key': 0.5,
  'obj_key1': 4000,
  'obj_key2': '2020-05-01',
  'obj_key3': 0.0,
  'obj_key4': 'US',
  'obj_key5': 50000,
  'obj_key6': 11,
  'obj_key7': 0.0,
  'obj_key8': 20000,
  'obj_key9': 0.01,
  'obj_key10': '6786547',
  'obj_key11': None,
  'obj_key12': 12},
 {'obj_key': 0.4,
  'obj_key1': 5000,
  'obj_key2': '2020-05-02',
  'obj_key3': 0.0,
  'obj_key4': 'US',
  'obj_key5': 657435,
  'obj_key6': 112,
  'obj_key7': 0.0,
  'obj_key8': 678548,
  'obj_key9': 0.032,
  'obj_key10': '6786547',
  'obj_key11': None,
  'obj_key12': 13},...]
```

Code:

```
import csv
import json
import requests

token = {token}

with open('../folder/file.csv') as src, open('target_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as tgt:
    reader = csv.reader(src)
    writer = csv.writer(tgt)

    columns = next(reader)

    writer.writerow(columns)

    headers = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }

    for id, name, date, data in reader:

        response = requests.get(f'https://{base_url}/api/endpoint?start_date=2021-05-01&end_date=2021-05-15' + '&id=' + str(id),
            headers=headers
        )

        response_data = response.json()
        for i in range(len(response_data)):
            data = writer.writerows(map(lambda x: [response_data[i]['obj_key1']], range(1)))
```

Expected CSV Output:

| id | name | date | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6786547 | Name | 2020-05-01 | 4000 |
| 6786547 | Name | 2020-05-02 | 5000 |

Comment: You only getting the only the last date's data because each time the `data = response_data[i]['obj_key']` line executes it replaces the previous value of `data`—so at the end of the `for` loop the last thing assigned to it will be its value.

Comment: @martineau thanks, I noticed that was what was happening. The trouble I'm facing is getting around that so all values are added to the CSV, not just the last value that has replaced the previous.

Comment: I don't really know the format of the input data or what's in each row of the CSV, basically you have to do something with `data` inside that `for` loop — maybe write a row of the CSV or accumulate the values and write the row using what's in more than one of them.

Comment: I updated the above code with my most recent edit that got me the individual pieces of data from each object, but now it is only showing up on the first row, so now I have to figure out how to write it to that specific 'data' column.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question and showed an example pf what the JSON data looked like as well as what it would look like after being converted into CSV format.

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: Where is the `Name` column data coming from?

Comment: `id` & `name` are already in the original CSV. I'm passing the `id` into the query with that code to get the resulting data, which I am trying to pull the `obj_key1` results from and into the data column.

Comment: Each time you call `writerow()` in the `for` loop you will need to pass it *all* four items (id, name, date, and data). The last two will come from the `response_data`. There's no need to use `map()` and a `lambda` when calling it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going recommend something that looks very different, but should get the job done all the same.

The big idea for me is to split the process up into distinct chunks—it'll be much easier for everyone to understand.

### Read first

I've chosen to save all the API reads into a list of dicts that will be written-out with the CSV **DictWriter** in the next part.

```py
import csv
import requests

path = f'https://{base_url}/api/endpoint?start_date=2021-05-01&end_date=2021-05-15'
token = {token}
headers = {
    'Authorization': token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}

final_rows = []
with open('../folder/file.csv') as src:
    reader = csv.reader(src)
    next(reader)  # discard this header, will be created from dict row

    for my_id, name, date in reader:  # omitted `data` from input
        response = requests.get(path + f'&id={my_id}', headers=headers)

        # Assuming `response.json()` looks like the sample JSON you provided
        for json_data in response.json():
            final_row = {
                'id': my_id,
                'name': name,
                'date': date,
                'data': json_data['obj_key1']
            }

        final_rows.append(final_row)
```

I mocked up `final_rows`, which looks like:

```py
final_rows = [
    {
        'id': '6786547',
        'name': 'Name',
        'date': '2020-05-01',
        'data': '4000'
    },
    {
        'id': '6786547',
        'name': 'Name',
        'date': '2020-05-02',
        'data': '5000'
    }
]
```

### Then, write

Now, `final_rows` will almost just write itself:

```py
with open('target_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as tgt:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(tgt, fieldnames=final_rows[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(final_rows)
```

and I get:

```
id,name,date,data
6786547,Name,2020-05-01,4000
6786547,Name,2020-05-02,5000
```

Comment: Or just `writer.writerows(final_rows)`?

Comment: @chepner, thanks, modified my code!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to implement what I suggested in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452137/add-data-to-specific-column-using-writerows-lambda#comment124543318_70452137) about calling `writerow()` multiple times and passing it all four columns (`id`, `name`, `date`, and `data`). You might be able to optimize it to create the rows first and then make one call to `writerows()` instead, but it's doubtful to me whether it would be worth the effort.

Note it seems odd to me that you're ignoring the `date` in `'obj_key2'` of each object of the list in the response and using the one in CSV file being read — but that seems to be what you said in your question.

```
import csv
import json
import requests

token = {token}

with open('../folder/file.csv', 'r', newline='') as src, \
     open('target_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as tgt:
    reader = csv.reader(src)
    writer = csv.writer(tgt)

    writer.writerow(next(reader) + ['data'])  # Copy header row and add column.

    headers = {'Authorization': token,                           
               'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

    for id, name, date, data in reader:
        response = requests.get(
            f'https://{base_url}/api/endpoint?start_date=2021-05-01&end_date=2021-05-15' 
            f'&id={id}', headers=headers)

        for obj in response.json():
            writer.writerow([id, name, date, obj['obj_key1']])
```